# Power BI too current date filter / dynamic bookmark

Tags: date, powerbi

So I have a sales KPI's page in power bi with 2 full years of data and the current year which is updated monthly / daily, So in order to display data up to the current month we have data for and compare them with prior years I currently have to select all the months individually so for this month I have to make 11 clicks on a month slicer to not be comparing a skewed amount of data with the prior full years..

so my question would be, is there a way to make a slicer or button for an entire page to click just once and show data for only up to the completed dates of data in the current year, just to help efficiency for the end user. I don't want a measure to add to every single visual, just a button or slicer on the page to turn off and on.

I want to stay away from relative date filters that do not update automatically, I don't want to have to go in every month and change it on my end, I want the end user to just push an action button.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried relative date filters? You can set it to this year https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range

Comment: @Jon Hello! Thank you for the reply, I should have included that in my post so sorry, I am looking for a method that stay away from a filter on the back end that I would have to change and republish every month, I want it to change to be the current day automatically for time efficiency.

Comment: Relative date filters don't normally require changing every month, they will take the current date then filter the table for the year or what ever you define

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that will fit your use case.

1. Use the relative date filter, that will show the data for the current year

In this example the relative date filter is set for this year, and will only show the date in that range. The dataset does contain values from 2019 to 2021, but only shows 2021.

[image]

2. The second option is to create a calendar table with items such as 'Current Month', 'Current Year', 'Current Day' etc to drive that filtering if the relative date filter doesn't fit your use case. This example works out the current year

[image]

You can set the page filter to filter on items in the current date range, every time the dataset refreshes, it will update the range to take into account the current day, year, month or what ever you define